# Can I write $\log^2{x}$ in skmath?

Tags: math-mode, packages, amsmath

Standard LaTeX has the opportunity to write things like `$\log^2{x}$`. This is however no longer possible when loading the `skmath` package, because `skmath` expects the logarithm to be entered `$\log[<base>]{<expression>}$`.

Did I miss something or is it only possible to achieve this by re-redfining `\log`.

PS: I am aware that `$\log{<expression>}^2` is mathematically the same and have set it thus for now, but the above method seems more reader-friendly to me.

Comment: well you don't need to redefine log if you want to keep the skmath one  but you could add a new macro of whatever name you want  that does `\mathop{\mathrm{log}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible redefinition of the syntax, if you are willing to accept this syntax as a solution:

```
\log[<base>][<exponent>]{<expression>}
```

The required redefinition:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand\log{oom}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\ensuremath{\__skmath_log:\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\c_math_superscript_token{#2}}\__skmath_parens:n{#3}}}
    {\ensuremath{\__skmath_log:\c_math_subscript_token{#1}\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\c_math_superscript_token{#2}}\__skmath_parens:n{#3}}}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

A complete document, with a multitude of test cases showing the behavior for omitted/empty arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand\log{oom}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\ensuremath{\__skmath_log:\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\c_math_superscript_token{#2}}\__skmath_parens:n{#3}}}
    {\ensuremath{\__skmath_log:\c_math_subscript_token{#1}\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\c_math_superscript_token{#2}}\__skmath_parens:n{#3}}}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  \log[10][2]{x} \\
  \log[10][]{x} \\
  \log[10]{x} \\
  \log[][2]{x} \\
  \log[][]{x} \\
  \log[]{x} \\
  \log{x} \\
  \log[10][2]{} \\
  \log[10][]{} \\
  \log[][2]{} \\
  \log[][]{}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to enable `^` with some sort of `t^` that checks if a optional token `^` is there and then take the next argument?

Comment: @Manuel it seems possible. I'm looking into it. This is my first foray into `expl3` so it is slow-going for me at the moment. Thanks for the suggestion. :-)

Comment: It's not necessary expl3. A main macro with arguments `{ o t^ }`, and then inside of it `\IfBooleanTF{#2}{…}{…}` that checks if the `^` is there, and, in case it's call an auxiliar macro, and in case it isn't call other auxiliar macro. That way you could enable `\log[12]^2{x}` (but I'm not saying I would like that, just that it's possible).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but I thought I should give an alternate method to contrast the accepted answer.

Using xparse, you can use embellishments to allow for a syntax like:

```latex
\log*{x}^{yy}_{zzz} % with parentheses
\log{x}^{yy}_{zzz}  % without
```

[image: logs]

It would be something like the following, and note there may be technical reasons that I am unfamiliar with as to why using these embellishments may be bad

```latex
\let\oldlog\log
\RenewDocumentCommand{\log}{s m e{_^}}{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \mathrm{log}%
        \IfValueT{#3}{_{#3}}%
        \IfValueT{#4}{^{#4}}%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\!\left(#2\right)}{#2}%
    }%
}
```

Comment: Adding `\ensuremath` is a bad habit. Being able to type `\log{x}_2` in text mode offers no advantage and obfuscates the code.